Agora Local Video Preview Not Showing - AgoraRtcEngineKit
I'm working on an iOS app using the Agora SDK (AgoraRtcEngineKit) for video calling. I've set up the Agora engine, but the local video preview is not showing on the screen. Here is a summary of the problem and what I've tried:
Issue: The local video preview, which should show the user's camera feed, is not appearing in the localVideoView. The localVideoView is properly linked in the storyboard and should be visible on the screen.
I expected the local video preview to be displayed in the localVideoView after setting up and starting the camera feed. The preview should show the user's camera feed, allowing them to see their own video before they join a call.
class BrandVideoCallingVC: UIViewController {
    
        // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var BaseView: UIView! // Base view to contain both video views
    @IBOutlet weak var localVideoView: UIView! // Local video view for the user's camera feed
    @IBOutlet weak var remoteVideoView: UIView! // Remote video view for the other participant
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCameraSwap: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnMicMute: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCallDisconnect: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTimer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    
        // MARK: - Variables
    var localVideo: AgoraRtcVideoCanvas?
    var remoteVideo: AgoraRtcVideoCanvas?
    var agoraEngine: AgoraRtcEngineKit?
    var isMuted: Bool = false
    var isSpeakerEnabled: Bool = true
    var isCameraFront: Bool = true
    var timer: Timer?
    var callDuration: Int = 0
    var roomID: String?
    let appID = agora_key // Replace with your Agora App ID
    var token = ""
    var channelName = ""
    var userId: UInt!
    var brandCreatorVideoCallDetails: BrandCreatorVideoCallDetails?
    let socketChat = SocketManagerForChatAndVideoCall.shared
    
    private var isMutedAudio = false {
        didSet {
                // Mute local audio
            agoraEngine?.muteLocalAudioStream(isMutedAudio)
            btnMicMute.isSelected = isMutedAudio
        }
    }
    
    private var isSwitchCamera = false {
        didSet {
            agoraEngine?.switchCamera()
        }
    }
    
        // MARK: - Life Cycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.obtainUserToken()  // Ensure token and userID are obtained before joining channel
        setUpView()

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        
            // Ensure video socket is connected
        if socketChat.sockets[.video] == nil || socketChat.sockets[.video]?.status != .connected {
            socketChat.initialize(namespace: .video)
            socketChat.listenerRegister(namespace: .video)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        endCall()
            // Disconnect the chat socket when the view is about to disappear
        if let chatSocket = socketChat.sockets[.video], chatSocket.status == .connected {
            socketChat.disconnectSocket(namespace: .video)
        }
    }
    
        // MARK: - Custom Methods
    private func setUpView() {
        self.applyStyle()
        initializeAgoraEngine()  // Initialize Agora Engine
        setupLocalVideo()       // Set up local video for preview
        joinChannel()
        
        self.remoteVideoView.isHidden = true // Hide remote video view initially
        
        self.remoteVideoView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handler)))
        self.setObserver()
    }
    
    func setObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(videoCallEnded),
                                               name: Notification.Name(rawValue: NotifyObserverKeys.videoCallEnded.rawValue),
                                               object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func videoCallEnded(_ notification: Notification) {
        if userType == .brand {
            UIApplication.shared.setHomeForBrand()
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.setCelebrityHome()
        }
    }
    
    private func applyStyle() {
            // Add custom styling here if needed
    }
    
        // MARK: - User Token Acquisition
    func obtainUserToken() {
            // Check which type of user is logged in and fetch their token and user ID accordingly
        let isUserExist = AppUtils.checkUserDefaultKeyAlreadyExist(kUsernameKey: CacheKeys.userLoginData)
        let isCelebrityExist = AppUtils.checkUserDefaultKeyAlreadyExist(kUsernameKey: CacheKeys.celebrityLoginData)
        let brandToken = UserModel.isUserLoggedIn
        
        if isUserExist || isCelebrityExist || brandToken {
            if isUserExist {
                    // Fetch token and user ID for a regular user
                let accessToken: UserLoginData? = UserDefaults.standard.getObject(forKey: CacheKeys.userLoginData)
                self.userId = UInt(accessToken?.getUserdata?.id ?? 0)
            } else if isCelebrityExist {
                    // Fetch token and user ID for a celebrity user
                let accessToken: CelebrityLoginModel? = UserDefaults.standard.getObject(forKey: CacheKeys.celebrityLoginData)
                self.userId = UInt(accessToken?.getUserdata?.id ?? 0)
            } else {
                    // Fetch token and user ID for a brand
                self.userId = UInt(UserModel.currentUser.brandId)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: User not logged in")
        }
    }
    
        // MARK: - Agora Setup
    func initializeAgoraEngine() {
            // Initialize the Agora engine
        agoraEngine = AgoraRtcEngineKit.sharedEngine(withAppId: appID, delegate: self)
        agoraEngine?.enableVideo()  // Enable the video mode
    }
    
    func setupLocalVideo() {
        guard let agoraEngine = agoraEngine else { return }
        
        localVideo = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
        localVideo?.uid = userId // Use userId for local video stream
        localVideo?.view = localVideoView
        localVideo?.renderMode = .hidden
        
        agoraEngine.setupLocalVideo(localVideo)
        agoraEngine.startPreview()  // Start the camera preview after setting up the local video
    }
    
    func joinChannel() {
        CallStateManager.shared.isCallActive = true
        
        let option = AgoraRtcChannelMediaOptions()
        option.clientRoleType = .broadcaster
        option.channelProfile = .communication
        
        agoraEngine?.joinChannel(byToken: token, channelId: channelName, info: nil, uid: self.userId, joinSuccess: { [weak self] (channel, uid, elapsed) in
            print("Joined channel: \(channel) \(uid) \(elapsed)")
            self?.emitCallStarted()
            self?.startCallTimer() // Start the timer
        })
        
        agoraEngine?.setDefaultAudioRouteToSpeakerphone(true)
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }
    func startCallTimer() {
        callDuration = 0
        lblTimer.text = "00:00"
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCallTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateCallTimer() {
        callDuration += 1
        let minutes = callDuration / 60
        let seconds = callDuration % 60
        lblTimer.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    }

    
    func setupRemoteVideo(uid: UInt) {
        guard let agoraEngine = agoraEngine else { return }
        
        remoteVideo = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
        remoteVideo?.uid = uid
        remoteVideo?.view = remoteVideoView
        remoteVideo?.renderMode = .hidden
        
        agoraEngine.setupRemoteVideo(remoteVideo!)
        
            // Show remote video view once the user joins
        remoteVideoView.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func leaveChannel() {
        agoraEngine?.leaveChannel(nil)
        emitCallDisconnected()
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
    }
    
    func endCall() {
        stopTimer()
        agoraEngine?.leaveChannel(nil)
        AgoraRtcEngineKit.destroy()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    @objc func handler(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gesture.location(in: self.view)
        let draggedView = gesture.view
        draggedView?.center = location
        
        if gesture.state == .ended {
            adjustVideoViewPosition()
        }
    }
    
    func adjustVideoViewPosition() {
        let tabPosition = self.BaseView.frame.size.height - (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height ?? 70.0) - 90
        let topHeight = self.statusBarHeight + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?? 70.0) + 30
        let leftMargin: CGFloat = 20
        let rightMargin = self.BaseView.layer.frame.width - 20
        
        if self.remoteVideoView.frame.midY >= tabPosition {
            if self.remoteVideoView.frame.midX >= self.BaseView.layer.frame.width / 2 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.y = self.BaseView.layer.frame.height - 150
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.x = rightMargin - 90
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.y = self.BaseView.layer.frame.height - 150
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.x = leftMargin + 90
                }
            }
        } else if self.remoteVideoView.frame.midY <= topHeight {
            if self.remoteVideoView.frame.midX >= self.BaseView.layer.frame.width / 2 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.y = topHeight + 90
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.x = rightMargin - 90
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.y = topHeight + 90
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.x = leftMargin + 90
                }
            }
        } else {
            if self.remoteVideoView.frame.midX >= self.BaseView.layer.frame.width / 2 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.x = rightMargin - 90
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.remoteVideoView.center.x = leftMargin + 90
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
        // MARK: - Button Actions
    @IBAction func cameraSwapTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            self?.isSwitchCamera.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func micMuteTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isMuted.toggle()
        isMutedAudio.toggle()
    }
    
    @IBAction func callDisconnectTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        emitCallDisconnected()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
        // MARK: - Emit Events
    func emitCallStarted() {
        print("Call started")
    }
    
    func emitCallDisconnected() {
        print("Call disconnected")
        let params: [String: Any] = ["room_id": self.brandCreatorVideoCallDetails?.roomId, "call_id": self.brandCreatorVideoCallDetails?.id, "call_duration": "90"]
        socketChat.emitCallEndEvent(namespace: .video, with: params)
        if userType == .brand {
            UIApplication.shared.setHomeForBrand()
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.setCelebrityHome()
        }
    }
}

    // MARK: - AgoraRtcEngineDelegate
extension BrandVideoCallingVC: AgoraRtcEngineDelegate {
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didJoinChannel channel: String, withUid uid: UInt, elapsed: Int) {
        print("Did join channel: \(channel), with uid: \(uid)")
    }
    
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didLeaveChannelWith stats: AgoraChannelStats) {
        print("Did leave channel")
    }
    
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didOccurError errorCode: AgoraErrorCode) {
        print("Error occurred: \(errorCode.rawValue)")
            // Show an alert or handle the error based on the code
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "An error occurred with code: \(errorCode.rawValue)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didVideoEnabled enabled: Bool, byUid uid: UInt) {
        print("Video enabled: \(enabled) by uid: \(uid)")
        if enabled {
            setupRemoteVideo(uid: uid)
        }
    }
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didJoinedOfUid uid: UInt, elapsed: Int) {
//        isRemoteVideoRender = true
        
        var parent: UIView = remoteVideoView
        if let it = localVideo, let view = it.view, view.superview == parent {
            parent = localVideoView
        }
        print("User joined with uid: \(uid)")
        
        if remoteVideoView != nil {
            return
        }
        
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: parent.frame.size))
        remoteVideo = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
        remoteVideo!.view = view
        remoteVideo!.renderMode = .hidden
        remoteVideo!.uid = uid
        parent.addSubview(remoteVideoView!)
        agoraEngine?.setupRemoteVideo(remoteVideo!)
//        labelTime.stopBlink()
        
    }
    
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didVideoMuted muted: Bool, byUid: UInt) {
        isMutedAudio = !muted
    }
    
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, didOfflineOfUid uid: UInt, reason: AgoraUserOfflineReason) {
        if let it = remoteVideo, it.uid == uid {
            remoteVideo = nil
        }
        
        switch reason {
        case .quit:
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {[weak self] in
                guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
  
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {[weak self] in
                guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
            }
            break
        case .dropped:
            /*callDissconectedDueToNetwrokIssues*/()
            print("callDissconectedDueToNetwrokIssues")
            break
        case .becomeAudience:
            print("becomeAudience")
            break
        @unknown default:
            print("default")
            break
        }
    }
}

